# How can I force Authenticate.php middleware respond with a json object not return redirect if I use an API? I have JWT login

Tags: laravel, api, middleware, jsonresponse

```
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            abort(response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'data' => 'Unauthorize'
            ]));
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I tried this but doesn't matter whether the condition is true, it nevershows me data i should / souldn't be able to see (doesn't matter that I provide a token or no).

This is how I call it in controller

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api');
    }
```

api.php

```
    Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'api',
], function ($router) {`
    Route::post('login', [\App\Http\Controllers\AuthController::class, 'login']);
    Route::post('register', [\App\Http\Controllers\AuthController::class, 'register']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`  add this

```php
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;

protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    return $request->expectsJson()
        ? response([
            'success' => false,
            'data' => 'Unauthorize'
        ])
        : redirect('/login');
}
```

> **NOTE**:_ it will work if you add header `Accept:application/json`

Comment: Sorry, I added header Accept:application/json but it didn't help.

Comment: yeah, sure I added it